# IPv6: ip-based or name-based vhost?

Tags: ipv6, virtualhost

With IPv4 the recommended type of vhosts is name-based since you need only one IPv4 address. IP-based vhosts should only be used if name-based doesn't work (because of TLS for example)

With IPv6 there is no need to save addresses. Wouldn't it be better to use IP-based vhosts instead of name-based vhosts? What could be a reason to use a name-based vhost with IPv6?

Comment: If you're going "IP-based", is it even still a vhost?

Comment: According to [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/) it is

Comment: Okike doke....!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name-based is easier because you don't have to adjust your network configuration for every website you host. Address-based is nice because every website you host is more easily identifiable in e.g. firewall policies, traffic management and monitoring, DDOS prevention etc.

The best choice depends more on your personal preferences, available management tools and other circumstances than anything else.